# Ionic To Django POST data auto name change

Tags: django, ionic-framework

Hi I am building an application in which my Ionic App need to send a post message to Django Backend.

My data at Ionic end during pos seem to be like this

```
// This is the value from ion-select with multiple set true

let data = {'selectedId':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

In my django request.POST the data is converted like this

```
<QueryDict : {u'selectedId[]' : [u'1',u'2',u'3',u'4',u'5']}>
```

Why does the key value automatically converted from "selectedId" in Ionic to "selectedId[]"

if i try to get the array value in Django by performing

```
request.POST['selectedId[]'] this give me the length of the array 5 
request.POST['selectedId'] this give me a MultiValueDictKeyError
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is because you are posting the values to you django endpoint as form-encoded values.  When you post non-file values that are form-encoded, they are **always** posted as strings.  If you want to preserve the type of the input you are passing in, you should use a JSON post instead of a form post.

Comment: i am converting the form values into a JSON value before sending it to Django Endpoint.

Comment: It does not appear that you are.  If you are accessing json values, you should be parsing `request.body`.  You are accessing values by `request.POST` which means those values are being posted as form encoded values, not JSON-encoded.

Comment: I figured it out, Ionic HTTP convert the provided information into string value. So if i pass my own object like passData = { 'foo':['bar','bar','bar']} as data in ionic HTTP it convert the given object into a string while sending it to Django backend.
I converted the given object into string using JSON.stringify(passData) and sent it as {'passData' : JSON.stringify(passData)} to http.post() call and used json.load under Django backend to parse the value properly.